# Sitecore User Group Nov 2018 Meetup - Queen City, Manchester, NH

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

We are wicked thrilled to announce the November meetup of the Queen City Sitecore User Group!

Two excellent presentation are lined up for this SUG:

1. Introduction to Sitecore JSS - Himadri Chakrabarti, Sitecore MVP at Nish Tech Inc
2. "SXA Nuptial Experiment" - Rodrigo Peplau, Sitecore MVP at Nish Tech Inc

Date & Time (EST):- Wednesday, Nov, 14, 2018 6:00 PM

Date & Time (UTC):- Wednesday, Nov, 14, 2018 10:00 PM

Venue:- SilverTech Inc, 196 Bridge Street, Manchester, NH 03104

[Click here](https://www.meetup.com/Queen-City-Sitecore-User-Group/events/254690825/) for more details and RSVP.

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins on Nov 7 at 22:00